# While loop in Matlab converges when it should not

Tags: matlab, while-loop

Consider the following algorithm in Matlab:

```
base10=2/5;
r=base10;
appr=[];
while r ~=0
appr=[appr; floor(4*r)];
r=4*r-appr(end);
end
```

which is supposed to transform the decimal point `base10` in base 4, specifically listing in `appr` all the converted digits after the comma.

I think this algorithm is wrong because `r` becomes `zero` at the `27th` iteration of the while loop producing a wrong last digit equal to `2`.

I am asking your help to understand why this happens.

If I manually do the while loop, the algorithm, rightly, does not converge because, indeed, `2/5` in base `4` is a repeated number.

Comment: The variable `base10` is not stored in a decimal (base 10) representation. The value `2/5` is calculated in finite precision and stored in its binary representation in a finite number of bits. Therefore, your conversion terminates.

Comment: I see, thanks. Probably a stupid question, but is there a way to store `base10' in a decimal representation? Moreover, does the issue mentioned above happens only for repeated numbers, right? For non-repeated numbers it should be okay, I think.

Comment: Sure, there's a thing called [binary-coded decimal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary-coded_decimal). As the name implies, it encodes the decimal representation of a number using binary. It's inefficient in both time and space complexity. It would be far more productive, imho, to understand the limitations of precision and how to deal with them, because they aren't going away. This should help: http://floating-point-gui.de

Comment: As far as when you will have precision problems, they will occur whenever the precision of the number you're trying to store is greater than the precision of the numeric type you're storing it in. As extreme examples, try storing `0.5` in an integer, or `pi` in any floating point type. Storing everything in decimal doesn't solve the problem either: `pi` is still a problem, as is `1/3`.